# Elegant way to transform Tightly Coupled Methods to Loosly Coupled using threadpools

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

1. I could not come up with a better title so would appreciate edits.
2. The problem I have is that a lot of methods exposed by libraries take a lot of time as they do a lot of brainy work or block on I/O ... for example when I ask Solr to index a document.
3. So to work around this problem what I end up doing is writing wrapper code that essentially makes the call to the method in the run() method of a Thread. I kick of worker threads to achieve parallelism and then extract the results and tally them up against the original calls.
4. It dawned on me that someone may have come up with a elegant way to do this, essentially:

   1. Take a method
   2. Get some sort of a Factory method to transform it into an async call
   3. Additionally wrap an ExecutorService around this so you can queue us the calls and have a pool of worker threads chug through it all.

suppose I have a class like:

```
public class SomeUtilClass {

  public int someComplicatedTask(int x, int y, int z) {
    // some very very complicated IO CPU bound task
  }

  // other equally lifting methods go here
}
```

Is there an elegant way to put a Thread Pool and task Queue in front of each method.

so basically I do something like this:

```
wrappedObject = EncapsulateWithThreadPoolAndTaskQueueFactory.wrap(SomeUtilClass,
    10 /*worker threads*/);

String ticket1=wrappedObject.asyncExecSomeComplicatedTask(1,2,3);
String ticket2=wrappedObject.asyncExecSomeComplicatedTask(4,5,6);
String ticket2=wrappedObject.asyncExecSomeComplicatedTask(7,8,9);

wrappedObject.joinOnTicket(ticket1); 
int result1=wrappedObject.getRestTicket(ticket1);
```

and so forth ...

Answer (score 2):

We've used a `TaskFactory` system with callbacks for our stuff before. Namely, we used it for requests and responses, but it could be used for many things. Basically, you would have a `TaskFactory` interface:

```
public interface TaskFactory<T, R> {
    Callable<R> taskFor(T t);
}

public interface Callback<R> {
    void onCallback(R r);
    void onException(Throwable t);
}
```

For request/response stuff, we used an instance of `TaskFactory<Request, Response>` to give us `Callable` instances for `Request` objects that do network I/O and return the `Response`:

```
public class RequestTaskFactory implements TaskFactory<Request, Response> {
    public Callable<Response> taskFor(Request request) {
        return new RequestTask(request);
    }
}
```

And the task:

```
class RequestTask implements Callable<Response> {
    private final Request request;

    public RequestTask(Request request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public Response call() {
        // Open socket
        // Send request
        // Receive response
        Response resp = getResponse(socket);
        return resp;
    }
}
```

The last interface and class tie it all together:

```
public interface TaskHandler<T, R> {

    TaskFactory<T, R> getTaskFactory();

    Future<R> submit(T t);

    void submit(T t, Callback<R> callback);
}
```

You can also have another method that will execute the callback on the event dispatch thread with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` if you like, in case you're using Swing at all. The implementation:

```
public class TaskHandlerImpl<T, R> implements TaskHandler<T, R> {

    private final ExecutorService executor;
    private final TaskFactory<T, R> taskFactory;

    public TaskHandlerImpl(TaskFactory<T, R> taskFactory, int threadPoolSize) {
        this.taskFactory = taskFactory;
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    }

    public TaskFactory<T, R> getTaskFactory() {
        return taskFactory;
    }

    public Future<R> submit(T t) {
        return executor.submit(taskFactory.taskFor(t));
    }

    public void submit(T t, Callback<R> callback) {
        executor.execute(new CallbackTask(taskFactory.taskFor(t)
    }

    private static class CallbackTask<R> implements Runnable {
        private final Callback<R> callback;
        private final Callable<R> callable;

        CallbackTask(Callback<R> callback, Callable<R> callable) {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.callable = callable;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                callback.onCallback(callable.call());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                callback.onException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's pretty much just a matter of writing your `TaskFactory`, `Callable`, and `Callback` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Another option besides my more general concurrency answer is to use Java's [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class.

Let's say you have a class `Foo` and you want to wrap it so that it will do all its methods in a background thread. It has a method `doSomething` that takes a long time to execute.

```
public class Foo {

    public void doSomething() {
        // network I/O or something
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

To use `Proxy`, you need an interface. (See [this tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-2000/jw-1110-proxy.html).) Create an interface from `Foo`:

```
public interface Foo {
    void doSomething();
}
```

And make your old `Foo` class implement your new interface:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo { ... }
```

Java's `Proxy` needs two things to work: the interface (got that) and an [`InvocationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html). The `InvocationHandler` is what will execute the methods in the background threads.

Here's how we can create the `Proxy` with an instance of `FooImpl`:

```
Foo foo = new FooImpl();
foo = (Foo) Proxy.newInstance(
        System.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] { Foo.class },
        new BackgroundInvocationHandler(foo));
```

Pretty simple, really. Now we just have to write `BackgroundInvocationHandler`:

```
public class BackgroundInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 20;
    private static final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);

    private final Object obj;

    public BackgroundInvocationHandler(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        executor.execute(new MethodInvoker(m, args, obj));
        return null;
    }

    private static class MethodInvoker implements Runnable {

        private final Method m;
        private final Object[] args;
        private final Object target;

        MethodInvoker(Method m, Object[] args, Object target) {
            this.m = m;
            this.args = args;
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                m.invoke(target, args);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // TODO log me
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I'm sure you probably expected, this will only work well with methods that return `void`. The `Proxy` instance will return `null` for anything that returns something that's not `void`. However, you can always combine this with callbacks or event dispatching to get results back from this stuff. Remember that this is like submitting jobs and leaving them, so you won't get anything back without implementing some kind of callback system.

Just one more remark: if you want to make sure *all* your objects are wrapped, then you'll need a factory to create the `Foo` objects:

```
public class FooFactory {
    public static Foo createFoo() {
        Foo foo = new FooImpl();
        foo = (Foo) Proxy.newInstance(
                System.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { Foo.class },
                new BackgroundInvocationHandler(foo));
        return foo;
    }
}
```

And then make `FooImpl` package-private so no one outside of the package can access it by removing `public` from the class declaration:

```
class FooImpl implements Foo { ... }
```

And there you go. This is a good way to wrap your objects to do background invocation with simple method calls. This code will execute `doSomething` in the background and print the given statement immediately:

```
Foo myFoo = FooFactory.createFoo();
myFoo.doSomething();
System.out.println("Prints immediately without waiting");
```

This is a lot closer to what you wanted compared to my other answer, but is more limited because of the return type requirements.

Comment: +1  I like this better than your TaskFactory idea, which seemed a bit "overkill" for my tastes.

Comment: @user949300 This doesn't quite fit the bill exactly, but yes, it's less code and more specific to the question, which is why I posted it. On the other hand, most background threads result in some calculated value, and the task-based system makes the process pretty transparent. It's a good pattern for more complex concurrent applications.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of various (and likely multiple) client classes making little wrappers about the code, I prefer to implement Runnable or Callable versions of the method *where they are implemented*, to encourage users (by making it easy) to use them asynchronously.  Obviously this means you anticipated that they will be used asynchronously.  You can even pass along arguments.  e.g.

```
public class Foo {

   public String someLongMethodA(Object...args) {
      // code that takes a long time here
      return someResult;
   }

   public Callable<String> callableLongMethodA(final Object...args) {
      return new Callable<String>() {
         @Override
         public String call() throws Exception {
            return someLongMethodA(args);
         }

      };
   }


   public Integer someLongMethod2(int loopCount) {
      // yet more long running code here
      return 42;  // the meaning of life
   }

   public Callable<Integer> callableLongMethod2(final int loopCount) {
      return new Callable<Integer>() {
         @Override
         public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return someLongMethod2(loopCount);
         }         
      };
   }  


}
```

This is far from perfect cause you are writing a lot of boilerplate code.  But that's what Eclipse templates are for.  Also, in some cases ,you have to be careful that the client doesn't change the arguments after making the initial call.